# Keycloak installation showing errror: Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to install `keycloak` server from the zip (version 6.1) by running standalone.bat on Windows 10. And I am facing the following issue.

ErrorImage

[image]

```
Calling "D:\Softwares\keycloak\keycloak-6.0.1\a\keycloak-6.0.1\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "D:\Softwares\keycloak\keycloak-6.0.1\a\keycloak-6.0.1"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman "

===============================================================================

Exception in thread "main"


  org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from D: \Softwares\ keycloak\ keycloak - 6.0 .1\ a\ keycloak - 6.0 .1\ modules\ system\ layers\ base\ org\ wildfly\ security\ elytron - private\ main\ module.xml
at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java: 339)
at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java: 295)
at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java: 256)
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.parseModuleXmlFile(LocalModuleFinder.java: 250)
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.lambda$findModule$1(LocalModuleFinder.java: 195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.findModule(LocalModuleFinder.java: 195)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule0(ModuleLoader.java: 693)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java: 686)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java: 496)
at org.jboss.modules.DelegatingModuleLoader.preloadModule(DelegatingModuleLoader.java: 57)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java: 1252)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java: 1622)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java: 1650)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java: 296)
at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java: 437)


Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to add resource root 'unnamed'
at path 'wildfly-elytron-1.8.0.Final.jar'(position: END_TAG seen...s > \n < resource - root path = "wildfly-elytron-1.8.0.Final.jar" / > ...@39: 64) caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D: \Softwares\ keycloak\ keycloak - 6.0 .1\ a\ keycloak - 6.0 .1\ modules\ system\ layers\ base\ org\ wildfly\ security\ elytron - private\ main\ wildfly - elytron - 1.8 .0.Final.jar(The system cannot find the file specified)
at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResourceRoot(ModuleXmlParser.java: 1131)
at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResources(ModuleXmlParser.java: 945)
at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java: 710)
at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java: 471)
at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java: 337)
  ...15 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D: \Softwares\ keycloak\ keycloak - 6.0 .1\ a\ keycloak - 6.0 .1\ modules\ system\ layers\ base\ org\ wildfly\ security\ elytron - private\ main\ wildfly - elytron - 1.8 .0.Final.jar(The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile. < init > (ZipFile.java: 225)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile. < init > (ZipFile.java: 155)
at java.util.jar.JarFile. < init > (JarFile.java: 166)
at java.util.jar.JarFile. < init > (JarFile.java: 145)
at org.jboss.modules.xml.JDKSpecific.getJarFile(JDKSpecific.java: 33)
at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser$DefaultResourceRootFactory.createResourceLoader(ModuleXmlParser.java: 1628)
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.lambda$new$0(LocalModuleFinder.java: 103)
at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResourceRoot(ModuleXmlParser.java: 1129)
  ...19 more
Press any key to
continue...
```

Comment: Please add error in comment,please follow SO standard .

Comment: Hi, that image is incredibly hard to read. Impossible for me even. Please try to copy the error and paste it as a text to make it easier to read and give others a chance to copy relevant parts of it to help you identify the problems and provide solutions.

Comment: I have updated the question. Take a look now.

Comment: I had this problem when I extracted the KeyCloak tar.gz download file. I used the .zip file and this error went away.